# Remove text from string php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called 'filename'. I try to output `<a>` tags in a loop from it like this:

```
<?php

while($sermon = mysql_fetch_assoc($sermonsQ)) {
    echo '<a href="admin/'. $sermon ['filename'] . '">';
    echo 'download</a></td>';
}
```

Current problem is, that `$sermon['filename']` containts a leading path like `path/test.mp3`. But I need only the filename without the path, like `test.mp3`. How can I do this?

Comment: pathinfo() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php with the PATHINFO_BASENAME argument

Comment: I guess you mean field/column and not table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`basename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) for that. It will return the filename without the leading path:

```
basename($sermon ['filename'])
```

Comment: :) np. You should consider to improve the code example in the question to something that is at least valid PHP code. Maybe it will get up-voted then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [path_info()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

also mysql_* functions are depracated so you shouldn't use them for example to PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

while($sermon = mysql_fetch_assoc($sermonsQ)) {
    $filename = explode('/',$sermon ['filename']);
    echo '<a href="admin/'. $filename[1] . '">';
    echo 'download</a></td>';
}
```